# CIVICRM export des formulaires

Tags: wordpress, drupal, cms-integration

Bonjour, 
je souhaites utiliser civicrm mais j'aimerais savoir si des extensions / plugins existent qui me permettent d'utiliser les formulaires (paiement, evenement, don, adhesion...) sur des sites sous wordpress, drupal, ou autre cms type spip par exemple. 
Merci pour votre aide !

---

Hello, I want to use civicrm but I would like to know if extensions / plugins exist which allow me to use the forms (payment, event, donation, membership ...) on sites under wordpress, drupal, or other cms type spip for example. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenue sur Stack Exchange. Il existe de nombreuses extensions qui peuvent être ajoutées à CiviCRM qui étendent / ajoutent à la fonctionnalité. Vous pouvez voir une liste des extensions publiées / révisées [sur CiviCRM.org](https://civicrm.org/extensions) et de nombreuses extensions non publiées [sur GitLab](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions)

Si vous utilisez WordPress, il existe également des plugins spécifiquement liés à CiviCRM qui permettent l'intégration, comme avec les formulaires Caldera.

---

Welcome to Stack Exchange. There are many extensions that can be added to CiviCRM which extend/add to the functionality. You can see a list of published / reviewed extensions [on CiviCRM.org](https://civicrm.org/extensions) and many unpublished extensions [on GitLab](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions)

If you use WordPress, there are also plugins specifically related to CiviCRM which allow integration such as with Caldera forms.

Answer (score 0):

CiviCRM does not work with SPIP. If you 'must' retain a SPIP CMS then you would need to use one of the 3 CMS it does work with as a front end for CiviCRM and perhaps theme it to look like the SPIP site, then bounce them to CiviCRM forms, or use a method for embedding forms on the external SPIP site